# Android code to apply same double tap touch listener on two or more different custom views

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

How to apply same double tap touch listener on two or more different custom views?

```
view1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
view2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) 
    {
        displayPTZControlsPopup(corresponding view id); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(VideoView.this,FullScreenVideo.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) 
    {
        return true;
    }
});
mGestureDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(true);
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this :

```
view1.setOnTouchListener(this);
view2.setOnTouchListener(this);

@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if(view.getId() == idOfYourView1 || view.getId() == idOfYourView2) {
        //Apply the method to one of the view touched
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Let me check

Answer (score 1):

try this code :

```
        GestureDetectorCompat gdc = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,new SimpleOnGestureListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) { 
        /*Your block of code*/
        /*(In my Case)*/
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Your_activity.class));
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Then assing the code to Your view as :

```
    myview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview);
    myview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            gdc.onTouchEvent(event);
           return true;
       }
   });
```

It just Worked for me...